# ActionListener при работе с Java Swing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swing, awt

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся цвет textField'а... Но необходимо, чтобы реализовалось условие: если цвет background коричневый, то он меняется на красный.
Ни ошибок, ни предупреждений мне не выдает, но при компиляции программы ничего не работает.

```
JButton roomButton1 = new JButton("Hotel Room №1");
JTextField roomField1 = new JTextField();

roomField1.setBackground(new Color(153, 51, 0));
roomField1.setForeground(new Color(255, 102, 0));

//Кнопки и ActionListener
roomButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (roomButton1.getBackground() == new Color(153, 51, 0)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Номер успешно забронирован!");
            roomField1.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 0));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Так же пробовал применить вариант с roomButton1.getBackground().getRGB() == new Color(153, 51, 0) - Все равно не получается

Comment: вы сравниваете цвета через == по факту разные экземпляры с одинаковыми значениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сравнивать единожды созданные объекты, а не каждый раз новые:

```
public class so_1017232 {

static Color c1 = new Color(69, 153, 60);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f  = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton roomButton1 = new JButton("Hotel Room №1");
    JTextField roomField1 = new JTextField();
    roomField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    f.add(roomField1);
    f.add(roomButton1);

    roomField1.setBackground(c1);
    roomField1.setForeground(new Color(255, 102, 0));

    roomButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (roomField1.getBackground() == c1){
                roomField1.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 0));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Номер успешно забронирован!");
            }}
    });
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Объекты созданные через new, но с идентичными элементами по умолчанию не равны. ведь может же быть в селе 2 Ивановых Ивана Ивановича, но при этом разных....

Вы сравниваете экземпляры по ссылке, они разные, т.к. каждый раз для проверки Вы создаете новый объект.

Comment: К сожаление вновь бездействие при нажатии на кнопку!

Comment: @ArturVartanyan ну да, я код копировал Ваш и не посмотрел, изменил ответ, не то поле сравнивали(отвечаю с телефона и не внимателен)

Comment: Спасибо! Отлично!